# Get text from span using Jsoup (java)

Tags: java, html, text, jsoup

Hello I would like to get the value following "cotation" but I don't know how to do it.

```
<span id="brs-sl57350199c5a53">
    <span class="cotation">16.33 (c)</span>
</span>
```

I'm using Jsoup and this my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.boursorama.com/bourse/actions/cours_az.phtml").get(); 

Element loginform = doc.getElementById("content");  //brs-sl5734ff406037d
Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("span");  

for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {  
    String key = inputElement.attr("class");  
    System.out.println("Param name: "+ key);
}
```

And this is what I have:

```
Param name: cotation
```

Do you have any idea to be able to get the value instead of "cotation"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your loop :

```
if ("cotation".equals(key)) {
    System.out.println(inputElement.html());
}
```

And you will get :

```
16.33 (c)
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed !!